# Is std::make_unique<T[]> required to return aligned memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14

- Is the memory owned by the unique pointer `array_ptr`:

  ```
  auto array_ptr = std::make_unique<double[]>(size);
  ```

  aligned to a <strike>`sizeof(double)`</strike> `alignof(double)` boundary (i.e. is it required by the std to be correctly aligned)?
- Is the first element of the array the first element of a cache line?
- Otherwise: what is the correct way of achieving this in C++14?

Motivation (update): I plan to use SIMD instructions on the array and since cache lines are the basic unit of memory on every single architecture that I know of I'd rather just allocate memory correctly such that the first element of the array is at the beginning of a cache line. Note that SIMD instructions work as long as the elements are correctly aligned (independently of the position of the elements between cache lines). However, I don't know if that has an influence at all but I can guess that yes, it does. Furthermore, I want to use these SIMD instructions on my raw memory inside a kernel. It is an optimization detail of a kernel so I don't want to allocate e.g. __int128 instead of int.

Comment: It sounds like you want aligned storage rather than aligned types. Types are always at least as large as their alignment, which isn't what you want at all. Maybe try `std::aligned_storage`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess that aligned storage is what I meant when I said aligned memory. Sorry about the confusion with sizeof vs alignof (I didn't knew about alignof).

Answer (score 8):

- All objects that you obtain "normally" are suitably aligned, i.e. aligned at `alignof(T)` (which need not be the same as `sizeof(T)`. That includes dynamic arrays. (Typically, the allocator `::operator new` will just return a maximally aligned address so as not to have to worry about how the memory is used.)
- There are no cache lines in C++. This is a platform specific issue that you need to deal with yourself (but `alignas` may help).
- Try `alignas` plus a static check if it works (since support for over-aligned types is platform dependent), otherwise just add manual padding. You don't really care whether your data is at the *beginning* of a cache line, only that no two data elements are on the same cache line.

It is worth stressing that alignment isn't actually a concept you can check directly in C++, since pointers are not numbers. They are *convertible* to numbers, but the conversion is not generally meaningful other than being reversible. You need something like `std::align` to actually say "I have aligned memory", or just use `alignas` on your types directly.

Comment: "You don't really care whether your data is at the beginning of a cache line, only that no two data elements are on the same cache line." For e.g. false sharing you are right. But I want to use SIMD instructions on the array and I don't know the effect of the first element starting randomly in the middle of a cache line.

Comment: @gnzlbg: That's a very different problem!

Comment: If my data is suitably aligned it should still work even if the first element is not at the beginning of a cache line. But since cache lines are the basic unit of memory in every architecture that I know of, I'd rather just "do it right" and put my first element at the beginning of one.

Comment: Can you show how to do the static check for an unique_ptr to an array of doubles or how to use alignas directly? (or just point me to an example of those things somewhere else?).

Comment: @gnzlbg: Note that a type can never be smaller than its alignment (think arrays), so alignment seems like the wrong approach for vectorisation. If your compiler does auto-vectorising, consult its documentation on how to best let it do that. I'm not sure if operations on dynamically allocated memory will be magically vectorised (but it's possible?) unless you give the compiler some help.

Comment: I was thinking of [a check like this](https://ideone.com/k51QXa). Coming to think of it, it's probably not necessary, since the code wouldn't compile if the large alignment wasn't supported.

Comment: @gnzlbg: If you need to do it manually anyway, the point is moot. Just use the appropriate "vector integer type" (`__int128` or whatever), and it will do the right thing.

Comment: I'd rather have it as a dynamic array everywhere, and only adapt it within the kernel where I need the manual vectorisation. I'm using the appropriate type within the kernel but if I can guarantee that the elements will be correctly aligned, I can just launch the intrinsics on the array itself. Otherwise, I need to copy them within the kernel to the appropriate type to be sure. I'd rather skip this step. But since the alignment issue is more complicated than I thought I might just do it.

Comment: Sounds like you started on question X and now we're on question Y. A new question might get some new answers.

Comment: @david.pfx IMO the question is still exactly the same as when it started, I just added the motivation. 1) Does make_unique<T[]> gives me memory that is correctly aligned? 2) Does the first T element in that memory start at the beginning of a cache line? The answer seems to be 1) it should, 2) you don't know/can't check in C++ since it doesn't know about cache lines. The problem is that the first thing that happens when you ask a question is that sometimes the discussion goes into "why would you ever do that"/"why would anyone ever want to do that" instead of answering the question itself.

Comment: And after discussing these aspect it is sometimes hard to go back to the original question and saying "actually what is being asked makes sense, in some situations you want/need to do that".

Comment: @gnzlbg: It's still an X-Y problem, which you can tell easily because the simple answer is "Yes, the memory is 'correctly aligned'", but that doesn't help your case at all. The crucial part is that you want to enable some kind of autovectorization, which is important. As I said before, a type's alignment (X) is not sufficient to relate it to vectorizability (Y)... Furthermore, cache lines don't play a role, either - even if you aligned each `int` on a cache line, you'd only end up with *one* integer per cache line, not with a vector.

Comment: I don't want auto vectorization _at all_, I want to manually use vectorization intrinsics in manually unrolled loops. The intrinsics require the memory to be correctly aligned or they won't work correctly. I don't want an int per cache line either, I want the whole block of memory to _start at the beginning of a cache line and not in the middle of one_. The reason is that if you know the cache-line and vector unit size, you can unroll the loop to work on one or two cache lines at a time, while adding prefetching hints to obtain the next to cache lines. You can also mark cache lines hot/cold...